# How to format exampleblocks like theoremblocks in beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer

I want to make exampleblocks just like the theoremblocks with the same formatting as the theoremblocks (except I want the block header background color to be cyan). How can I do that? I tried to copy-paste a code that worked just fine for theorems and replaced 'theorem' with 'example', but it didn't work out. (I use \usetheme{Aalborg}).

```
\uselanguage{danish}
\languagepath{danish}
\deftranslation[to=danish]{Example}{Eksempel}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{example begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \begin{\insertexampleblockenv}
    {%
      \insertexamplename
      \insertexamplenumber
      \ifx\insertexampleaddition\@empty\else\    \insertexampleaddition\fi%
    }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{example end}{%
    \end{\insertexampleblockenv}%
}

\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

`example` inherits the formatting automatically from `theorem`, so you just need to adjust the colours:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Aalborg}

\uselanguage{danish}
\languagepath{danish}
\deftranslation[to=danish]{Example}{Eksempel}
\deftranslation[to=danish]{Theorem}{Saetning}

\undef{\example}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}


\makeatletter
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=orange,fg=black}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{}{
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=orange!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=orange!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=orange!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=orange!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=orange!100!black}%  
}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
    }%
    \normalfont%
}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
    \end{\inserttheoremblockenv}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{theorem}[test]
content...
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}[test]
content...
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{example}


\end{frame} 

\end{document}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Aalborg}

\uselanguage{danish}
\languagepath{danish}
\deftranslation[to=danish]{Example}{Eksempel}
\deftranslation[to=danish]{Theorem}{Saetning}

\undef{\example}
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{\translate{Example}}


\makeatletter
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=orange,fg=black}
\addtobeamertemplate{block example begin}{}{
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=orange!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=orange!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=orange!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=orange!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=orange!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=orange!100!black}%  
}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
  \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!white}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \setbeamercolor{enumerate subsubitem}{fg=cyan!100!black}%
  \begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
    {%
      \inserttheoremname
      \inserttheoremnumber
      \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ \inserttheoremaddition\fi%
    }%
    \normalfont%
}

\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
    \end{\inserttheoremblockenv}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{theorem}[test]
content...
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{theorem}

\begin{example}[test]
content...
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\end{itemize}
\end{example}


\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The colours in the example-environment is still the same as in the theorem-environment (both the colour of the block header and of the bullet-points). Furthermore, the example-counter now works for both examples and theorems, but I want seperate counters for each of these environments.

Comment: @PeterJensen The colour is definitely not the same, I added a screenshot

Comment: That's strange. When I use thecode provided (copy-pasted), then the colouring of the theorem-environment is ok, but the colouring of the example-environment is not. The background-colour of the exampleblock-header is always dgreen for some reason? And the colour of the bullet-points in an example is the same as the colour of the bullet-points in a theorem. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @PeterJensen Given that there is no `dgreen` in my code because in all your questions you never told use how this colour might be defined, I doubt that it is en exact copy paste. Try the exact same code as in my answer in a new document and report back.

Comment: When I make an exact copy-paste into a new document, then I get an error message: ! Undefined control sequence. 1.10 \undef {\example}

Comment: @PeterJensen Can you show the complete log file? If it is too long to add it to your questions, try something like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: I just signed up at pastebin.com. Username: PeterJensen. Name/title of the paste: Exampleblock-problem. The error concerning \undef is in line 810.

Comment: @PeterJensen Could you please give me a link? No idea how to search for a user name there

Comment: @PeterJensen Thanks, the link works fine! Many of your packages are very outdated. Can you update?

Comment: @PeterJensen Maybe `\let\example\undefined` instead of `\undef{\example}` works, but I no longer have a 2015 installtion to test.

Comment: @PeterJensen Narrowing down the problem: I think the problem is that your old beamer version does not yet automatically load the `etoolbox` package, so adding `\usepackage{etoolbox}` should also fix the problem

Comment: Maybe you are right about updating packages. I tried to reinstall MikTeX but now my problem is that I cannot reinstall it. It says: 'The specified installation directory is not empty'.